# How to access overlapping geojson/polygons to display in infobox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to load multiple polygons into the map using the geoJSON data layer. Some of these polygons overlap in certain regions. When a user clicks on a point that is inside of multiple polygons, I want to display the properties (name, tags, etc) in an InfoBox with the click event.

I'm wanting to display the properties of all the polygons for a given point. Currently when I click on a point I can only see one polygon, despite the point being inside of multiple polygons.

How can I access all the properties of all the polygons with Google Maps API v3?

```
const map = useGoogleMap(); // google map instance
const polygons; // an array of polygons, example snippet below. 

map.data.addGeoJson(polygons);

map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
   // how can i access other features underneath this clicked point
   console.log(event.feature); // only returns "Geofence 1"
})
```

example GeoJson:

```
polygons = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      "name": "Geofence 1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -8.96484375,
              -9.96885060854611
            ],
            [
              3.955078125,
              -9.96885060854611
            ],
            [
              3.955078125,
              -0.17578097424708533
            ],
            [
              -8.96484375,
              -0.17578097424708533
            ],
            [
              -8.96484375,
              -9.96885060854611
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      "name": "Geofence 2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -6.591796875,
              -8.320212289522944
            ],
            [
              2.197265625,
              -8.320212289522944
            ],
            [
              2.197265625,
              -1.9332268264771106
            ],
            [
              -6.591796875,
              -1.9332268264771106
            ],
            [
              -6.591796875,
              -8.320212289522944
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      "name": "Geofence 3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -4.39453125,
              -6.926426847059551
            ],
            [
              0.263671875,
              -6.926426847059551
            ],
            [
              0.263671875,
              -3.337953961416472
            ],
            [
              -4.39453125,
              -3.337953961416472
            ],
            [
              -4.39453125,
              -6.926426847059551
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the [containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.containsLocation) method in the geometry library.

> **containsLocation(point, polygon)**
> **Parameters:**
> **point:**  LatLng
> polygon:  Polygon
> Return Value:  boolean
> Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

Unfortunately that only works with native `google.maps.Polygon` objects not `Data.Polygon` objects.  Translate the data in the feature into native `google.maps.Polygon` objects, push them on an array, then process through the array to see which polygon(s) the click is in.

1. create `google.maps.Polygon` for each polygon in the input (assumes only polygons)

```
  var polygonArray = [];
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
    e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function(latLngArry){
      const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths: latLngArry.getArray(),
        clickable: false,
        name: e.feature.getProperty("name") // save the data we want to output as an attribute
      })
      polygonArray.push(polygon);
    })
```

2. on click check for which polygon(s) the click was in:

```
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i=0;i<polygonArray.length;i++) {
       if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, polygonArray[i])) {
          if (content.length!=0) 
            content+=" : "
          content += polygonArray[i].name;
       }
    }
    console.log(content);
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zv4132b9/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
// This example uses the Google Maps JavaScript API's Data layer
// to create a rectangular polygon with 2 holes in it.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var polygonArray = [];
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
    console.log(e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().length);
    e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function(latLngArry) {
      console.log(latLngArry.getArray())
      const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths: latLngArry.getArray(),
        clickable: false,
        name: e.feature.getProperty("name")
      })
      polygonArray.push(polygon);
    })
    processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  const features = map.data.addGeoJson(polygons);
  map.data.setMap(null);
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < polygonArray.length; i++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, polygonArray[i])) {
        if (content.length != 0)
          content += " : "
        content += polygonArray[i].name;
      }
    }
    console.log(content);
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = content;
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    if (content.length == 0) content = "no GeoFence";
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map);
  })

  function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
      callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
    } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
      callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
    } else {
      geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
        processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
      });
    }
  }
}
const polygons = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Geofence 1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-8.96484375, -9.96885060854611],
            [
              3.955078125, -9.96885060854611
            ],
            [
              3.955078125, -0.17578097424708533
            ],
            [-8.96484375, -0.17578097424708533],
            [-8.96484375, -9.96885060854611]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Geofence 2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-6.591796875, -8.320212289522944],
            [
              2.197265625, -8.320212289522944
            ],
            [
              2.197265625, -1.9332268264771106
            ],
            [-6.591796875, -1.9332268264771106],
            [-6.591796875, -8.320212289522944]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Geofence 3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-4.39453125, -6.926426847059551],
            [
              0.263671875, -6.926426847059551
            ],
            [
              0.263671875, -3.337953961416472
            ],
            [-4.39453125, -3.337953961416472],
            [-4.39453125, -6.926426847059551]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Polygon</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this POC working with React and am sharing for next person who might be interested:

```js
import { InfoWindow, useGoogleMap } from '@react-google-maps/api';

export const GeofencesContainer = () => {
  const map = useGoogleMap();
  // geofence = geoJSON feature collections
  const [geofenceClickEventLatLng, setGeofenceClickEventLatLng] = useState({});
  const [geofencesProperties, setGeofencesProperties] = useState([]);
  const [isInfoWindowOpen, setIsInfoWindowOpen] = useState(false);
  const [polygonArray, setPolygonArray] = useState([]);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let addFeatureListener;
    const getGeofences = async () => {
      if (true) {
        if (ref.current !== 'geofenceEnabled') {
          // get geofences from api
          const geofences = await fetch.getGeofences(); 

          // a listener to add feature, where we create a google.maps.polygon for every added feature, then add it to the polygon array
          const addedPolygons = [];
          addFeatureListener = map.data.addListener('addfeature', e => {
            const featureGeometry = e.feature.getGeometry().getArray();

            // for each geometry get the latLng array, which will be used to form a polygon
            featureGeometry.forEach(latLngArray => {
              const polygon = new window.google.maps.Polygon({
                map,
                paths: latLngArray.getArray(),
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: 'green',
                clickable: false,
                name: e.feature.getProperty('name')
              });
              addedPolygons.push(polygon);
            });
            setPolygonArray(addedPolygons);
          });

          // add the polygon to the map data layer (this will show the polygon on the map and cause the addfeature listener to fire)
          map.data.addGeoJson(geofences);
          map.data.setStyle({ fillColor: 'green', strokeWeight: 1 });
          // we set map data to null so that we don't end up with 2 polygons on top of each other
          map.data.setMap(null);
          ref.current = 'geofenceEnabled';
        }
      } else {
        ref.current = null;
        for (const polygon of polygonArray) {
          polygon.setMap(null);
        }
        setIsInfoWindowOpen(false);
      }
    };
    getGeofences();

    return () => {
      if (addFeatureListener) {
        addFeatureListener.remove();
      }
    };
  }, [activeKmls]);

  useEffect(() => {

    let clickListener;
    if (true) {
      // a listener on click that checks whether the point is in a polygon and updates the necessary state to show the proper info window
      clickListener = map.addListener('click', function(event) {
        // this state is updated to identify the place where the info window will open
        setGeofenceClickEventLatLng(event.latLng);

        // for every polygon in the created polygons array check if it includes the clicked point, then update what to display in the info window
        const selectedGeofences = [];
        for (const polygon of polygonArray) {
          if (window.google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, polygon)) {
            const name = polygon.name;
        
            selectedGeofences.push({ key: name, name });
          }
        }
        if (selectedGeofences.length) {
          setIsInfoWindowOpen(true);
        } else {
          setIsInfoWindowOpen(false);
        }
        setGeofencesProperties(selectedGeofences);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (clickListener) {
        clickListener.remove();
      }
    };
  }, [activeKmls, polygonArray, altitudeUnit, map]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isInfoWindowOpen && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={geofenceClickEventLatLng}
          onCloseClick={() => setIsInfoWindowOpen(false)}
          zIndex={0}
          options={{ maxWidth: '450' }}
        >
          <Fragment>
            {geofencesProperties.map(geofenceProperties => {
              return (
                <Fragment key={geofenceProperties.key}>
                  <Title level={4}>{geofenceProperties.name}</Title>
                </Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </Fragment>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does this differ from the answer provided a couple of weeks earlier? (Other than that this answer lacks all explanation.)